# ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, mysql, boolean, resultset

I need help creating a boolean check for a method I made. I basically want it to return true if they have the specified EnumRank, but it's not working. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Both values are stored in VARCHARS

Code:

```
    public boolean hasRank(Player player, EnumRanks rank){
    if (!MySql.checkConnection()){
        return false;
    }
    try{
        String query = "SELECT RANK FROM `user_ranks` WHERE UUID= '" + player.getUniqueId() + "';";
        PreparedStatement statement = MySql.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        result.next();
        return result.getBoolean(rank.getSQLName());
        //return true - So I can use this method
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        //Nothing
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the rank to the query, and you're using `PreparedStatement` so use bind parameters. You can use `result.next()` to check if the query returns a result and you should use the finally block to close your `Statement` and `ResultSet` (and `Connection`). And don't silently swallow `Exception`(s). Something like

```
public boolean hasRank(Player player, EnumRanks rank) {
    if (!MySql.checkConnection()) {
        return false;
    }
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    String query = "SELECT RANK FROM `user_ranks` WHERE UUID=? AND RANK=?";
    try {
        conn = MySql.getConnection();
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, player.getUniqueId());
        statement.setString(2, rank.getSQLName());
        result = statement.executeQuery();
        return result.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```